# Replace some parts of a tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, addition

I have the following problem: I'm using a video on my website and want to open it in a lightbox. My CMS doesn't give me the possibility to open just the one video within a lightbox, but I think the technical backgrounds are too much for this question so now what I want to do:

I want to look with jQuery for the Video within my link, like '.mp4">' this part I want to replace or extend with something like this: '.mp4" **data-lightbox="video">**'.

The first thin I tried is .replaceWith but I think it just works with classes or ids? Maybe the code was wrong?

```
$('.mp4">').replaceWith('.mp4" data-lightbox="video">');
```

I used the search for different methods, but I think most are for something like text-changes or changes of ids and classes...

What I'm looking for is something, that can handle with the HTML, so that it just replace or add the code, which is necessary.

Regards,
Markus

Edit: The HTML:

```
    <a title="title" href="/files/videos/abc/abc.mp4">
<img alt="title" src="assets/images/f/abc.png">
</a>
```

Comment: If you look up `replaceWith()` you will see that it completely replaces elements

Comment: what attribute contains the `mp4` value? Show sample html

Comment: I edited to the html to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than manipulating the html as text I would probably manipulate the attributes using jQuery

This will select any with href ending with .mp4, you can change href to whatever the attribute name is if it's not href

jQuery Selector

```
$("[href$='.mp4']").attr("data-lightbox", "video")
```

You could use data instead like this:

```
$("[href$='.mp4']").data("lightbox", "video")
```

but this would not change the html and would only be read by using data("lightbox"). Having said that if it is to register the anchor for a lightbox plugin the second approach might work and I would say is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
 jQuery('.mp4').attr('data-lightbox','video')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested!

```
var content = $(body); // get content outer

var str = '.mp4" data-lightbox="video">'; // replacement string

var contentInside = content.innerHTML; // now get inner content

var newContent = contentInside.replace(/.mp4">/g, str); // replace ALL occurrences

$(body).html(newContent); // repopulate the outer
```

Hopefully that would do the trick - mixed vanilla and jquery for no reason other than to speed it up - not sure if the `>` in the replace would need escaping and can't test right now

Comment: this will remove  event handlers bound to all elements in the dom

Comment: Yes, it will - I'm just answering the OP - even with this they will need doc find instead of simple on click for the data-lightbox